# Easy Windows app development solution?

Tags: windows

I have been developing utility scripts to run on Windows (parse log files, make reporting on it, extract informations, read from database...).

Now I would like to go a bit further and transform those scripts in an application with a quick and dirty GUI (file selections, buttons, datagrid...).

What I'm looking for is an **easy way to make a GUI on Windows**, able to access the filesystem and execute other commands, requiring the least amount of installation possible and with a free IDE.

I have thought about several solutions but can't find one that fits all: `HTML5/Javascript` (can't access filesystem, run programs...), `Visual Basic 6` (not free and need to install libraries), `C++`/`C#` (not really RAD, takes time), `Java` (takes time to make a GUI)...

Is there a magic solution? (I've read that in Windows 8, we will be able to develop *real* Windows applications using HTM5/JS)

Comment: Please explain the close votes -_-

Comment: Please tell in what language you had your scripting-experience, .BAT batch-files?

Comment: I wouldn't put C++ and C# on the same boat as of RADness.

Comment: Telling us which language you have experience in helps us make appropriate suggestions.

Comment: @eznme Batch, PHP and Shell script files (cygwin). As for the language I have experience with: DHTML, Java, VB6, PHP, bits of C++... But as long as the language is not too complicated, it shouldn't be a problem I think

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) might be a good solution for you, and should address most of your requirements. It's a scripting environment with GUI capabilities and a lightweight editor.

Edit : This answer sucks, I should have paid more attention to your question.

Comment: It seems to be a scripting language for manipulating other application's GUI (simulating keystrokes, mouseclicks, etc...)